# Simple shell loop fail in Makefile

Tags: bash, make, programming, gnu-make

Why does the shell loop

```
 l='abc de f'; for k in $l ;{ echo $k; }
```

inside Makefile not work ?
instead only give

```
 abc de f
```

at once
How to solve such in the definitive way?

Comment: please post a complete example; if the shell code you posted is used as a Makefile _recipe_, it will NOT produce that output; it will either error out or not print anything.

Comment: Seeing this in a an actual Makefile context would be beneficial. Please update your question with a Makefile that exhibits the described behaviour.

Comment: @mosvy the term `recipe` does not exist in the official `make` terms. You probably mean the term `make command line` instead.

Comment: @schily This is not make. This is [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipes.html#Recipes)

Answer (score 2):

It should not work outside Makefile too because `do` and `done` are missing:

```bsh
l='abc de f'; for k in $l; do echo $k; done # this works
```

In Makefile, `$` need to be escaped and it becomes:

```
    l='abc de f'; for k in $$l; do echo $$k; done
```

Comment: `for i in ...; { ...; }` works in ksh, Bash and zsh, though, but it's not standard.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks for pointing it out. Just tried it and you are right. I have never seen this syntax before and he missed the first `;` before editing so...

Comment: Did you intend to double the $$ for the L variable?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes. In makefiles one has to type $$ to get a single dollar sign.

Comment: @ilkkachu make should always use `/bin/sh`, not `$SHELL` to execute the recipes -- this is required by the standard (they should be passed to the `system(3)` function).

Comment: @mosvy, sure. But the syntax isn't completely off as it's actually supported by some shells, and could even work in a makefile if `/bin/sh` is Bash... (Not with the semicolon missing of course.)

Comment: This still does not completely solves the mystery, as the shell would split the expansion of the unquoted variable `l`, yielding three separate words, not one.